# How does the concatenation work between CNN and normal features

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a problem. I have trained a CNN model for an NLP classification problem and combined it with other features.
I am using [`Concatenate`](https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/concatenate/) to concatenate the two layers with it.

My question is how does this chaining work? How can this be thought of?

```py
class CNN_1D:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def forward(self):
            # filter_sizes = [1,2,3,5]
            # num_filters = 32
            extra_nb_features = df_train.shape[1]

            inp = Input(shape=(maxlen, ))
            extra_inp = Input(shape=(extra_nb_features, ))

            x = Embedding(embedding_matrix.shape[0], 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(inp)
            x = SpatialDropout1D(0.4)(x)

            x = Conv1D(256, 7, activation='relu')(x)
            x = MaxPooling1D()(x)

            x = Dropout(0.2)(x)  
            x = Flatten()(x)
            combined = Concatenate(axis=-1)([x, extra_inp])

            combined = Dropout(0.15)(combined)

            outp = Dense(numbmer, activation="softmax")(combined)

            model = Model(inputs=[inp, extra_inp] , outputs=outp)
            model.summary()
            return model
```

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually the first input `inp` is embedded and passed through all the layers that have `x` as an output. `extra_inp` is a set of raw inputs that are passed in with the convoluted `inp` to the `Concatenate` layer to return a single set of inputs (a tensor) that is going to be used for the final prediction. `Concatenate` merges both inputs, the ones that are “preprocessed” and the unaltered ones. You can check more details in the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/concatenate/)

Here's a toy model that can be used as en example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, Flatten, Concatenate, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Model

inputs = Input(shape= (32,1))
h = Conv1D(filters= 16, kernel_size= 5, activation= 'relu', padding= 'same')(inputs)
h = Flatten()(h)
aux_inputs = Input(shape= (12,))
h = Concatenate()([h, aux_inputs])
output = Dense(20, activation= 'sigmoid')(h)

model = Model(inputs= [inputs, aux_inputs], outputs= output)
```

The summary of the model:

[image: multiple input model]

The convolution layer takes a batch of 32-dimensional vectors and returns a tensor with shape `batch_size, new_input_dimension, filters`. In this case, the model is configured to have `padding = 'same'` so the dimensions remain the same. The output of the `Conv1d` layer is then unrolled by a `Flatten` layer for it to have the right shape to concatenate it with the extra input (which is also one dimensional). Finally, this extended tensor is passed in to the final `Dense` layer to return the output of the model.

The following graph is quite straightforward:

[image]

Hope you find it helpful!

Comment: Could you give an example of how the concatenation works?

Comment: yup, just added an example to the answer